# Constructors should only call non-overridable methods in SonarQube tool

Tags: java, sonarqube

In `JersyConfiguration` class i am getting sonar tool major issues like **Remove this call from a constructor to the overridable "register" method**. I really don't understand with what code change can resolve this issue. This is my code:

### JerseyConfiguration

```
public class JerseyConfiguration extends ResourceConfig {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
        objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
        objectMapper.enable(MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES);
        objectMapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.READ_ENUMS_USING_TO_STRING);
        return objectMapper;
    }



    @Autowired
    public JerseyConfiguration() {
        register(TermsResourceImpl.class);
        register(AccessIDResourceImpl.class);
        register(CatalogResourceImpl.class);
        register(SubmitOrderResourceImpl.class);
        register(ValidateAndQuoteResourceImp.class);
        property(ServletProperties.FILTER_FORWARD_ON_404, true);
        register(DynamicLoggingFeature.class);
        register(ContextFilter.class);
        register(ServiceExceptionMapper.class);
        register(JsonParseExceptionMapper.class, 1);
        register(JsonMappingExceptionMapper.class, 1);
        register(LoggingContextJerseyFilter.class);
        register(FeatureToggleFilterBinder.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public Client jerseyClient() {
        return ClientBuilder.newClient(new ClientConfig());
    }
}
```

### ResourceConfig  overide methods

```
 @Override
 public ResourceConfig property(final String name, final Object value) {
     state.property(name, value);
     return this;
 }

 @Override
 public ResourceConfig register(final Class<?> componentClass) {
     invalidateCache();
     state.register(componentClass);
     return this;
 }
```

### SonarQube issue

[image: SonarQube issue description]

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis it may be a false positive, as it's a valid jersey code as https://blog.dejavu.sk/registering-resources-and-providers-in-jersey-2/

Comment: Yeah I was about to add another duplicate for suppressing it. The first one properly explained why the warning occurs.

Comment: I have similar code which SonarLint which doesn't find any code smell, How exactly do you check your code?

Comment: @user7294900 after deployed my code in environment we check sonar issues there its showing this issue

Comment: I think you should raise it in SonarQube site as false positive or at least discuss it there

Answer (score 1):

It is not a false positive, because the rule works correctly. You are calling a method in the constructor which could be changed in sub classes. This structure could cause problems. Example:

```
public class BrokenCode extends JerseyConfiguration {

    @Override
    public ResourceConfig register(final Class<?> componentClass) {
        // stop invaliding cache, to break the application
        // invalidateCache();

        state.register(componentClass);
        return this;
    }
}
```

---

To solve the issue the method must be marked as `final`. I don't know Jersey so you have the following option:

#### 1. if making methods as `final` is impossible

In some cases adding `final` could break the application, because for example dynamic proxies are created by the used framework. In such cases you can only mark the issue as `Won't Fix` (it informs other developers that the mentioned structure doesn't match the rule, but you are fine with it)

#### 2. if making methods as `final` is possible

There are two options, depending on which classes you can edit:

1. if you can edit the `ResourceConfig` class, then change:

```
@Override
public ResourceConfig register(final Class<?> componentClass) {
    invalidateCache();
    state.register(componentClass);
    return this;
}
```

to

```
@Override
public final ResourceConfig register(final Class<?> componentClass) {
    invalidateCache();
    state.register(componentClass);
    return this;
}
```

If `invalidateCache` is not `private` then you have to mark it as `final` too.

2. if you cannot edit the `ResourceConfig` class, then you can add to the `JerseyConfiguration` class the following method:

```
@Override
public final ResourceConfig register(final Class<?> componentClass) {
    super.register(componentClass)
}
```

Of course again if `invalidateCache` is not `private` then you have to add it too:

```
@Override
public final void invalidateCache() {
    super.invalidateCache()
}
```

---

The chosen "fixing" strategy should be based also on:

- used framework (Jersey) guidelines
- who can extend `JerseyConfiguration` configuration
- etc.

I think it is totally fine to close it as `Won't Fix` also when the application:

- uses structures in the used framework documentation
- is developed/maintained only by your team (nobody else creates manually new instances of the `JerseyConfiguration` class)

Answer (score 0):

Add an explicit 'this' to the register() calls.

Example:

```
public class JerseyConfiguration extends ResourceConfig {

  @Autowired
  public JerseyConfiguration() {
    this.register(TermsResourceImpl.class);
    this.register(AccessIDResourceImpl.class);

    ...

  }
}
```